# how do i create OGRSpatialReference from raster file's georeference C++

Tags: gdal, vector, ogr, georeferencing, c++

I want to create .shp file using ogr with georeference based on my raster file, so i create an ogr layer using CreateLayer( "point_out", **NULL**, wkbPoint, NULL ); i want to set the OGRSpatialReference variable from **NULL** to to my raster file's georefrence, all i know to get raster file georefrence is using GetProjectionRef() function. how do i convert this to OGRSpatialReference ? or there is some other way to done that ?

(note i'm using c++ programming language)

Answer (score 3):

Use the wkt from GetProjectionRef to create a OGRSpatialReference:

```
const char *pszWkt = poDS->GetProjectionRef();
OGRSpatialReference oSRS;
oSRS.importFromWkt(&pszWkt);
```

See docs: http://gdal.org/classOGRSpatialReference.html#ab74cfc985bd05404a4c61d2d633a6343

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the official documentation does not give an example that will properly compile due to a typo. According to the current documentation the "importFromWkt" takes a `char**` parameter.

The following snippet works however:

```
const char *pszWkt = poDS->GetProjectionRef();
char *pszWkt_tmp = (char *) pszWkt;
OGRSpatialReference oSRS;
oSRS.importFromWkt(&pszWkt_tmp);
```